# How to access baseURL of axios instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, instance

I put this question up in order for easy access of the solution for fellow developers searching for an answer

//If you have an axios instance declared in a module similar to this, say, api.js

```
var axios = require('axios');

var axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://example.com/foo/bar',
    /* other custom settings */
});

module.exports = axiosInstance;
```

//If you are accessing the module somewhere else, like this

```
var api = require('./api');

api.get('relative/path')      //For a typical get call using an instance
```

But, you want to find the baseURL for some business requirement from an axios instance and not necessarily make a call, how do you find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults

in your case should be : `baseURL = api.defaults.baseURL`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, i did use the same solution though.... :)

Answer (score 1):

My Api js file

const instance = axios.create({
baseURL: "http://localhost:3157/api/v1", your base url
headers: {
"Content-type": "application/json",
},
});

export default instance;

import instance from 'api.js';

let baseURL = instance.dafaults.baseURL;

Answer (score 1):

```
var axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://example.com/foo/bar',
    /* other custom settings */
});

//Use this --> "axiosInstance.getUri()"
console.log(axiosInstance.getUri());
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```